# Why does encoding a video using the MJPEG codec take longer than MPEG-4?

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, mpeg4, mjpeg

I am testing the encoding performance (MPEG-4 and MJPEG) of a smart camera. I have written an application in OpenCV/FFMPEG for performing encoding, where the application captures images from the camera and encodes them to a desired encoding format. In the benchmarks, I came to know that MJPEG encoding is taking much longer than MPEG-4 encoding. I expected it to be other way around. Encoding a single frame to MPEG-4 takes around 31ms, whereas encoding to MJPEG takes around 80ms. Does MJPEG really takes such a long time in comparison to MPEG-4?

Comment: I would have expected it to be the other way 'round as well. Maybe the MJPEG encoder is not as optimized as the MPEG-4 encoder (are we talking `libavcodec`?)

Comment: yes. It's libavcodec. I use OpenCV for encoding which, in turn, uses FFMPEG/libavcodec.

Answer (score 3):

The two compression algorithms are *completely different* in the way they function, and MPEG4 can use GPU acceleration as well.

MPEG4 is a true video codec, whereas MJPEG simply compresses each frame into a separate JPEG image.  The difference is that MPEG4 uses a variety of techniques (motion vector compensation, I/B frames, etc...) to enhance both quality and compression ratio.

Why one works faster then the other case really depends on **how the encoder was implemented**, and on **how your particular hardware performs** when encoding.  Some encoders can use special CPU instructions (SSE/SSE2, MMX, etc...), or use GPU acceleration (I know you probably don't, but I'm just mentioning it).  JPEG compression is largely CPU speed dependent, and doesn't really use any instruction set enhancements (for compatibility/stability, and the fact that [it doesn't really help](http://mjpeg.sourceforge.net/) - see the changelog entry for November 16, 2006).

Lastly, unless you have a single-frame video, MPEG4 never really encodes a "single frame" at a time.  It always performs frame look ahead/behind to determine better ways to compress the current frame (MJPEG *does* only do a single frame at a time).  As such, it is largely dependent on the data before/after the frame, not only on the current one.  This occurs in single-pass encoding as well (that's why it uses the motion vectors in the first place, after all).

Comment: At present, the camera is covering a completely static scene. Is it possible that the static scene increases the performance of MPEG-4 (as it works on motion vectors) and there is not much overhead involved in MPEG-4 encoding in this case? Could it be the reason why it is performing much better than MJPEG in this case? As I said earlier, every time I capture a frame from the camera, I write it down to a file using OpenCV/FFMPEG (in MPEG-4 and MJPEG format respectivley).

Comment: In this case, **yes**, because the predictive encoding of a static scene is highly efficient. This is where MPEG-4 beats MJPEG.

Comment: @slhck it is only efficient with respect to the compression ratio, it does not encode faster.  That being said, if it is a static scene, you can reduce the number of I/B frames and decrease the macroblock calculations to increase your encoding speed without affecting quality too much.

Comment: @Breakthrough Given the right MB search algorithm, yup. I guess though that in this case, the implementation of the MJPEG encoder is rather weak.

Answer (score 0):

MPEG-4 encoding is much more cpu-intensive than MJPEG. Your camera likely has MPEG4 encoding hardware built-in, which is why it can process MP£G4 data mushc quicker.